# syntax to remove permissions previously granted via GRANT EXECUTE?

Tags: t-sql

If I grant execute permissions to a role via

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [DBO].[MYPROC] TO MY_ROLE
```

what's the equivalent syntax to remove them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

REVOKE EXECUTE ON [DBO].[MYPROC] TO MY_ROLE

Answer (score 14):

```
DENY EXECUTE ON [DBO].[MYPROC] TO MY_ROLE
```

or

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON [DBO].[MYPROC] TO MY_ROLE
```

depending on your goal. The first acts as a filter for any granted permissions, the second removes an explict permission.

Answer (score 1):

```
DENY EXECUTE ON [DBO].[MYPROC] TO MY_ROLE
```